# UITableView as subview is always empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, subview

I have a ViewController which has several subviews (Graphs) added using function

```
[self.view addSubview:subView]
```

Now, I want to add a UITableView as subview, but when I do this, my table is always empty. Methods like numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection, etc are never called.
My table doesn't have a XIB file. This is the code from my .M file:

```
#import "TableSubviewViewController.h"

@implementation TableSubviewViewController

@synthesize data;
@synthesize tableFrame;

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style{
   self = [super initWithStyle:style];
   if (self) {
       // Custom initialization
   }
   return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.frame = tableFrame;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [[self.data allKeys]count];
}

-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[self.data allKeys]objectAtIndex:section];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 1; 
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Some text";   
    return cell;
}
```

And this is the code in my main ViewController, in which I'm creating TableSubviewViewController:

```
TableSubviewViewController *tableSubView = [[TableSubviewViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
tableSubView.tableFrame = tableFrame;
tableSubView.data = data;
[self.view addObject:tableSubView.view];
```

What Am I missing?
Thank you

Comment: Have you assigned tableView delegate and datasource to self?

Comment: Is TableSubviewViewController a subclass of UITableViewController or UIViewController? Is it set as the delegate and data source of the table? Also, what you're doing, adding its view to the view of ViewController shouldn't be done unless you make TableSubviewViewController a child view controller of ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

*TableSubviewViewController* **tableSubView** must be main *ViewController*'s  global variable , can't be a local variable in the method **viewDidLoad** of main *ViewController*

Answer (score 0):

U need to set datasource and delegate methods do like this

```
   // in TableSubviewViewController.h file put a custom initilizer 

   @interface TableSubviewViewController : UIViewController
   - (id)initTheSubviewTableVIewWithFrame:(CGRect)rect; //your custom initialiser
   @end

  //TableSubviewViewController.m file 
  #import "TableSubviewViewController.h"

  @interface TableSubviewViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

  @end

  @implementation TableSubviewViewController

   //dont use this method left blank
  - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
  {
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
     if (self) {
    // Custom initialisation
      }
      return self;
 }
    //you can make custom initiliser method
   - (id)initTheSubviewTableVIewWithFrame:(CGRect)rect
      {
         self = [super init];
         if(self)
        {
           UITableView *subViewTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];//since u are creating the tableview programatically u need to set datasource and delegate programatically
            subViewTable.dataSource = self; //add this
            subViewTable.delegate = self; //this also
            [self.view addSubview:subViewTable];
         }

          return self;
      }


     - (void)viewDidLoad
       {
         [super viewDidLoad];
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
       }

      - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
     {
         [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
      }

     //datasource and delegate methods
      -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
       return 2;
       }

      //use as reqired
      //-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:  (NSInteger)section{
      //    return 3;
      //}

      -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 1;
       }

     -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if(cell == nil){
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Some text";
    return cell;
   }

      //in  main ViewController.m controler u need to do like this
      TableSubviewViewController *subViewTable = [[TableSubviewViewController  alloc]initTheSubviewTableVIewWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, 150)];//created the subviewTableView tableview 
     //set properties that u defined for tableview delegate and datasource



     [self.view addSubview:subViewTable.view];
```

hope this helps u :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .h file use

and set delegate and datasource to self.

```
TableSubviewViewController *tableSubView = [[TableSubviewViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
tableSubView.tableFrame = tableFrame;
tableSubView.delegate = self;
tableSubView.dataSource = self;
tableSubView.data = data;

[self.view addObject:tableSubView.view];
```

After that check whether array self.data have object or not. It might be possible that array is blank.